# Subjuntivo en contextos volitivos

Tags: subjuntivo

Tengo un problemilla con el uso de modo Subjuntivo en contextos volitivos.

Podeis echar un vistazo a las frases abajo y decir cuales creeis que son correctas y cual es vuestra logica al elegir entre Indicativo y Subjuntivo?

Las frases:

1. **Me** gusta que (**Mari**) ES tan insistente
2. **Me** gusta que (**Mari**) SEA tan insistente
3. **Me** gusta que (**yo**) SOY tan insistente
4. **Me** gusta que (**yo**) SEA tan insistente
5. **Le** gusta que (**yo**) SOY tan insistente
6. **Le** gusta que (**yo**) SEA tan insistente
7. Lo que **me** gusta de **Mari** es que ES tan insistente
8. Lo que **me** gusta de **Mari** es que SEA tan insistente
9. Lo que **me** gusta de **mi** es que (**yo**) SOY tan insistente
10. Lo que **me** gusta de **mi** es que (**yo**) SEA tan insistente
11. Lo que **le** gusta de **mi** es que (**yo**) SOY tan insistente
12. Lo que **le** gusta de **mi** es que (**yo**) SEA tan insistente
13. Lo que **le** gusta de **mi** es que (**Mari**) no me PUEDE ganar
14. Lo que **le** gusta de **mi** es que (**Mari**) no me PUEDA ganar
15. Lo que no **me** deja de sorprender es que (**Mari**) nunca me PIDE nada
16. Lo que no **me** deja de sorprender es que (**Mari**) nunca me PIDA nada
17. Lo que no **me** deja de sorprender es que (**yo**) SIGO sin pedir nada
18. Lo que no **me** deja de sorprender es que (**yo**) SIGA sin pedir nada

Asi es como lo veo yo:

1-6: Segun la mayoria de los libros gramaticos en las frases tipo "me gusta que" solo se aplica subjuntivo, asi que las oraciones corectas serian los 2 y 6 (el 4 suena muy raro).

7-18: Aqui es donde empieza la confusion. Se ve que en cuanto nos alejamos del patron sintactico habitual las cosas se vuelven impredecibles, o sea, las respuestas varian de una persona a otra.

Mi logica a este respecto es la siguiente:

1. Modo subjuntivo trata una accion como algo distante de lo real;
2. "X (no) es real" es una evaluacion subjetiva, lo que implica que hay quien la realiza, y esta persona es la que dice la frase.
3. En la frase 12, por ejemplo, el uso de "SEA" puede ser - digo yo - una referencia a que el hecho de que yo "sea muy insistente" es nada mas que opinion de Mari, y no tiene que ser verdad.
4. En la frase 11, al decir "SOY", el hablante confirma que si lo es.
5. La frase 10 no tiene mucho sentido, ya que en ambas oraciones el hablante habla de si mismo (es como decir: "segun yo, yo sea insistente, pero es solo una opinion". - una situacion ridicula, a no ser que la persona tenga un trastorno de personalidad multiple).
6. Frases con verbos distintos de SER (como la 14) destruyen toda la logica anterior. Aunque lo que "no me puede ganar" sea un hecho indiscutible, mucha gente acepta el uso tanto del subjuntivo como del indicativo (cual es la diferencia entonces entre 17 y 18?).

Muchas gracias de antemano!

Seva

P.S. Perdon por no haber puesto accentos que no los tengo en mi teclado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día. Creo que ya había una pregunta similar yirando por ahí. En pocas palabras, el subjuntivo tiene un uso un poco más amplio que lo que piensa el común de la gente. Entre ellos, está el hacer concordancia en subordinadas que se unen a verbos que introducen juicios de valor.

Es lo que ocurre en 1-6. La estructura es: (sujeto) + GUSTA + que + (subordinada). Para estos casos, el verbo *gusta* requiere sí o sí el subjuntivo. Por lo tanto es correcto lo que pensaste.

> Le gusta que **SEA** tan/muy insistente.

En 7-18, la estructura es: (sujeto) + ES + que + (subordinada). El verbo *es* posee mayor versatilidad por lo que a grandes rasgos diría que se puede usar indicativo o subjuntivo. Sólo que, en tu caso particular, el uso de ‘tan’ junto con el indicativo da la sensación de que te falta mencionar algo más:

> Lo que le gusta de mí es que (yo) **SOY TAN** insistente ↗ [qué más?] **QUE siempre consigo lo que quiero**. ↘

> Lo que le gusta de mí es que (yo) **SOY MUY** insistente. ↘

> Lo que le gusta de mí es que (yo) **SEA TAN** insistente. ↘

Entonces, para este último grupo de oraciones, ‘muy’ queda mejor con el indicativo y ‘tan’ queda mejor con el subjuntivo. Pero también vale usar ‘tan’ con el indicativo siempre y cuando se complete con otra subordinada más.

En suma, el límite entre el ámbito de lo subjuntivo y lo indicativo es más difuso de lo que parece a simple vista. Además de los verbos (ser vs gustar), los adverbios (muy vs tan) también pueden ser influyentes a la hora de determinar la concordancia.

Y hacés bien en sospechar de 4. Porque la construcción ‘me gusta que (subjuntivo)’ se usa cuando una acción o evento acontecido superó la expectativa del hablante. Por lo tanto, la frase es ridícula; lo correcto sería:

> Me gusta **SER** **muy** insistente.

Otro ejemplo para que quede más claro:

> Me gusta que yo salga a correr por las mañanas. (ridículo)
> Me gusta **SALIR** a correr por las mañanas. (OK)

Comment: Muchas gracias, tac! Eso es lo que he sospechado: Desde el punto de vista sintactico la constuccion "Me gusta que..." significa precisamente eso: "Me gusta X", mientras que "lo que me gusta es que..." se puede interpretar como "Y es X": de ahi, creo, vendra la ambiguedad entre Subjunivo y Indicativo. Lo que has dicho sobre como "tan" y "muy" es una observacion muy importante! Gracias por señalarmelo! Pero por que crees que pasa eso? Otra vez, aqui esta lo que pienso yo. Segun los gramaticos, el objeto principal del Subjuntivo es hablar de algo que no es "declaracion...

Comment: Adverbio "TAN", utilizado solo, se aplica para dar una reaccion a lo que fue comentado anteriormente. En mi caso, cuando digo "...que soy tan insistente" ese "TAN" se refiere al grado de la insistencia que ya ha sido evidente para la otra persona - entonces, no declaro nada - entonces debo poner el verbo en subjuntivo. El adverbio "MUY", por otra parte, no tiene esta restriccion y puede llevar un matiz declarativo, o sea, introducir nueva informacion. Asi que, los adverbios, que hacen referencias a lo sabido, obligan el uso de indicativo, mientras que losotros no. Que te parece?

Comment: P.S. Te agradezco mucho lo detallada y reflexiva que ha sido tu respuesta!

Comment: No estoy seguro de cuál es la regla, si es que hay alguna. Pero ‘soy’ (indicativo) + ‘tan X que’  suele usarse para hacer una comparación o implicar algo más, por eso se pronuncia para arriba. Mientras que en los demás casos no necesariamente se da. ‘sea tan X’ puede usarse de las dos formas (‘que sea tan X’ o ‘que sea tan X que’). No creo que tenga que ver lo de introducir nueva información o no. ‘Muy’ y ‘tan’, ambos pueden introducir nueva información. Yo creo que se trata de los usos de cada adverbio, no estoy seguro de si hay una regla para eso.